# Powershell script automation backup dhcp database

Tags: powershell, backup, dhcp

I'm trying to create a script to automate copying database file from DHCP servers W2008 R2 into a shared drive in the central server using Powershell script. What I have in mind is to export the database file, and copy it to a shared drive.

```
#Get Yestedays Date In Month, Day, Year format
$yesterday=(get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -uformat %Y%m%d)

#Get the first 3 letters of the day name from yesterday
$logdate=([string]((get-date).AddDays(-1).DayofWeek)).substring(0,3)

#Create Temporary directory
Remove-Item -Path D:\TempBackup -Recurse mkdir D:\TempBackup

#Export DHCP database
netsh dhcp server export D:\TempBackup\"dhcpdatabase-$logdate.dat" all
restart-service dhcp

#Map to remote Share drive
New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root \\SERVER1\Share 

#Copy to share drive
Copy-Item D:\TempBackup\"dhcpdatabase-$logdate.dat" Y:\"dhcpdatabase-$logdate.dat"

#Rename file with yesterdays date
cd Y:\
rename-item "dhcpdatabase-$logdate.dat" "$yesterday.dat"
```

The purpose is to get the backup DHCP database just in case if the server crashes. The script will be running on each DHCP server using task scheduler once a month. Appreciate if you can give me example of the working Powershell script with versioning to overwrite the file.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't really need to do the export.  Windows DHCP servers use a jet database, and automatically maintain a backup copy of the .mdb file at %systemroot%\system32\dhcp\Backup\ .  You just need to save a copy of that .mdb backup.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? The code you posted should create DHCP database backups just fine once you add the missing line breaks.

Comment: @mjolinor Exporting the DHCP database has the advantage that you can easily restore it to a different server.

Comment: Thank You all, yes the purpose is to setup new dhcp server as fast as I could in the event of major crashes.

Comment: I have updated my script, let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: We don't usually do code reviews here. Is anything not working with your script in its current form?

Comment: I believe this will do exactly what you want in just a more simpler way. It backups the DHCP server automatically oto the backup server, creates a folder with the date and time stamp e.g DHCP_20170202_1738 http://www.thefunkytechguy.co.za/2017/02/the-simplest-way-to-backup-dhcp.html